# Browser enabled InfoPath Form Get local IP of a client

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

How do I get local IP of a client who opens InfoPath form in a browser ?

I did VSTO C# coding but this is not browser supported anymore, right ? What do you advise me to do ? i need local IP because of loging. Thank you.

```
public string getLocalIp()
    {
        IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        return localIPs[2].ToString();
    }

    public string getPublicIP()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string IP = webClient.DownloadString("http://myip.ozymo.com/");
        return IP;
    }

    // OPOMBA: program Microsoft Office InfoPath zahteva ta postopek.
    // Lahko ga spremenite s programom Microsoft Office InfoPath.
    public void InternalStartup()
    {
        root.SelectSingleNode("/my:getRacInfo/my:localIp", NamespaceManager)
        .SetValue(getLocalIp());
        //string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        root.SelectSingleNode("/my:getRacInfo/my:webIp", NamespaceManager)
        .SetValue(getPublicIP());
    }`
```